# Eclipse expression not allowing public method access

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a Java class which extends ArrayList and incorporates a HashMap of all the items in the list:

```
public class PayeeListMap extends ArrayList<Payee>
{
  private Map<String, Payee> payeeMap = new HashMap<String, Payee>();
  
  @Override
  public boolean add(Payee payee)
  {
    // if a record with this payee's key exists in the map, remove it from the list
    // before adding back the new one.
    // we don't need to remove it from the map; we're about to replace that.
    Payee existingRecord = payeeMap.get(payee.key);
    if (existingRecord != null) { remove(existingRecord); }
    
    // add the new record to the map and the list.
    payeeMap.put(payee.key, payee);
    super.add(payee);
    return true;
  }
  
...
```

I have testing code in a class in a variable named `tableModel`, and an instance of my own class within that named `payees`. I wanted to check on the size of both the list and the hashmap. If I enter the following expressions into the Expressions window, they work:

```
tableModel.payees.size()
tableModel.payees.payeeMap
```

But if I enter `tableModel.payees.payeeMap.size()`, I get "error(s) during the evaluation"; if I select the expression, there are two error lines:

```
The field PayeeListMap.payeeMap is not visible
The blank final field PAYEE_LOOKUP_FILENAME may not have been initialized
```

PAYEE_LOOKUP_FILENAME is a field in the tableModel class, a string variable with an initializer on it. I don't know why it would be considered 'possibly uninitialized' any more for `payeeMap.size()` than for `payeeMap`.

Is this just a bug in eclipse, or am I missing something?

[image: Expressions window]

Answer (score 0):

Your private Map<String, Payee> is **"private"** so requires a private method, if you need to access it make a private method and use in the same class and scope a public method to call the private method.

Comment: @Samuel_Marchant The expressions window in eclipse readily displays the value(s) for the Map (tableModel.payees.payeeMap) even though it is private. I'm wondering why it won't execute a public method on that variable. We're not in Java here, I'm not asking about scoping rules in running Java code. Whatever executes the Expressions window clearly knows about the internals of payeeMap, why wouldn't it execute `size()` on the payeeMap?